# Clear old data on rendering data from firebase react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from firebase but I get duplicate data on the app. I clear the state of orders before fetching and then combine all orders from different customers but the problem is that, I get prev. orders and prev. orders + new orders all combined. What I want prev. order + new order only.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let customerList1 = [];
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/serviceProvider/${user1.uid}/franchise/customers`)
      .orderByKey()
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        customerList1.push(snapshot?.val());
        setCustomerList(customerList1);
        // setCustomerList(snapshot.val());
      });
      setShowloading(false);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user1.uid]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const innerSubscriptions = [];
     // let orderList1 = [];
    
    if (customerList) {
      setOrders([]); // <-- clear orders 
      Object.values(customerList).forEach((customer) => {
        if (customer) {
          Object.values(customer).forEach((id) => {
            const unsubscribe = firebase
              .database()
              .ref(`/orders/${id}`)
              .orderByKey()
              .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
                // Grab all orders from the customers and merge
                const order = snapshot?.val();
                // setOrders([...orders, order]); // realtime but gets only last customerList orders
                setOrders((orders) => [...orders, order]); // realtime all orders but reapeated the list and new orders
                // setOrders((orders) => {
                //   return [...orders, order]
                // });
                setShowloading(false);
              });
            innerSubscriptions.push(unsubscribe);
          });
        }
        
      });
    }
    return () => {
      innerSubscriptions.forEach((unsubscribe) => unsubscribe);
    };
  }, [customerList]);
```

Comment: What do you fetch from firebase? All orders or all orders that are new?

Comment: All orders from given customer and when they order new item that too. But in that process all order get renders including new one and also keeps previously rendered item which needs to be removed or just add new order and merge with them